# Apex code using maps

Tags: apex

I am a beginner in apex coding. I need help to create an apex class which queries N no. of contact records then map it such that key is accountId and value is list.. 
basically I need to generate all the contacts related to an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map<Id, List<Contact>> mapAccountIdTolstContact= new map<Id, List<Contact>>();

for(Contact objContact:[SELECT Id, Email, Phone, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != null])
{
  if(!mapAccountIdTolstContact.containsKey(objContact.AccountId))
       mapAccountIdTolstContact.put(objContact.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
  mapAccountIdTolstContact.get(objContact.AccountId).add(objContact);
}

system.debug('=====mapAccountIdTolstContact======'+mapAccountIdTolstContact);
```

try to execute in developer console.
If you want for specific Account then filter by AccountId

---

```
public Class Chk {

    public void fetchAllAccount() {
        Map < Id, List < Contact >> mapAccountIdTolstContact = new Map < Id, List < Contact >> ();
        for (Contact objContact: [SELECT Id, Email, Phone, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != null]) {
            if (!mapAccountIdTolstContact.containsKey(objContact.AccountId)) mapAccountIdTolstContact.put(objContact.AccountId, new List < Contact > ());
            mapAccountIdTolstContact.get(objContact.AccountId).add(objContact);
        }
        system.debug('=====mapAccountIdTolstContact======' + mapAccountIdTolstContact);
    }
}
```

Now in developer console.

```
Chk obj = new Chk();
obj.fetchAllAccount();
```

Comment: hi thank u..it works perfectly in developer console but i have to write it in an apex class on force.com platform.. can u help me with that

Comment: @malvika http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/apex-class/

Comment: public Class Chk
{
Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapAccountIdTolstContact= new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();

for(Contact objContact:[SELECT Id, Email, Phone, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != null]){
  if(!mapAccountIdTolstContact.containsKey(objContact.AccountId))
      mapAccountIdTolstContact.put(objContact.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
  mapAccountIdTolstContact.get(objContact.AccountId).add(objContact);
}
system.debug('=====mapAccountIdTolstContact======'+mapAccountIdTolstContact);
}  ds code is throwing  Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'for' at line 5 column 0

Comment: Check my updated ans hope this will help you. I suggest first go with https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

Comment: thanx a ton :) finally it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It's not always a good idea to put objects into maps, especially if you might want to modify the contents of those objects. Instead, you may want to consider creating a map of Account Id to ContactId then have another map of ContactId to ContactObject, the latter of which is easy to do in a query and represents the relationship of the object's own Id to itself.

So, if you pass your list of AccountIds to your controller, you can then run a query that would look like this:

In your class, you'd have something like:

```
Public with sharing class controllerName{

Public list<Id>AcctsLst {get;}
Public map<Id,Id>Acct2Ctc {get;set;}
Public map<Id,Id>CtcMap {get;set;}

Public getContactMaps(list<account> AcctsLst){

Map<Id,contact>CtcMap = new map<Id,contact>([SELECT ID, Name, AccountId, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN: AcctsLst]);

return CtcMap
}

Public getAcctToCtctMap(list<account> AcctsLst, map<Id,contact> CtcMap){

map<ID,ID>Acct2Ctc = new map<ID,ID>();
for(Id cId:CtcMap.keyset()){

    for(Id aId:AcctsLst){
        if(CtcMap.get(cId).contains(aId)) Acct2Ctc.put(aId,cId);
    }
}

return Acct2Ctc; 

}   

}
```

With the combination of the above two maps, you should then be able to easily obtain whatever you want as the Id of the contact will not change, but the details of the contact might. Should the contact object change in the CtcMap, it will still be accessible using the values from the other map and a refresh from the controller.

**Edit**

If you truly only want a map of `accountId` to `list<contact>`, you'd want to change the above to include a method that looks more like what's below:

```
Public with sharing class controllerNameOfyourChoice{

    Public list<Id>AcctsLst {get;}
    Public map<Id,list<contact>>Acct2Ctclst {set;}


    getAccountCtcMap(list<account> AcctsLst){

    list<contact>ctclst = new list<contact>();
    ctclst=[SELECT ID, Name, AccountId, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN: AcctsLst]);


    for{account a:AcctLst){
        integer i=0;
        if(i!=0){
            Acct2Ctclst.put(a.Id,ctc.[i-1]);
        }
        for(contact c:ctclst){
             list<contact>ctc[i] = new list<contact>();
             if(c.accountId == a.Id){
                ctc[i].add(c);
        }
        i++;

        if(i>0){
            Acct2Ctclst.put(a.Id,ctc[i-1]);
        }
    }

    return Acct2Ctclst; 

    }   

}
```

Comment: thanq ..dats useful.. but can you provide me a solution with object using Map<Id, List<Contact>>..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a particular exercise or goal in mind.

One way to do this would be to retrieve the contacts with the account Id, iterate over the contacts then populate a map. This has already been addressed.

But if the requirement were to just get all contacts for an account, I might look to query the account with a contact subquery. For instance this:

```
Account myAccount = [select Id, Name, 
                       (select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contacts)
                     from Account
                     where Id = : myAccountId];
```

You then have access to all the contacts for that account:

```
List<Contact> thoseContacts = myAccount.Contacts;
```

Or, if you want to so something with an account Id map, then do this:

```
Map<Id, Account> acctMap = new Map<Id, Account>(
                     [select Id, Name, 
                       (select Id, FirstName, LastName from Contacts)
                     from Account
                     where Id in : myAccountIdListOrSet]);
```

Now you can use the account Id as a key to lookup Contacts.

```
Id someAcctIdVar = '001800000001010';
List<Contact> contactList = acctMap.get(someAcctIdVar).Contacts;
```

There is probably some marginally higher memory footprint to this way of getting it, but fewer iterations.